# Why does not linux kernel choice a thread oriented signal schema?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, signals

Now, linux signal is handled by any thread in a process. why does not linux take a thread oriented signal schema. In some case, the signal event raised by thread A also want to be solved by thread A And if the event has not been solved, thread A cannot going on. So does it possible to reimplement linux kernel's signal mechanisim?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? What "signal event" do you have in mind that would be "raised by thread A," and which must also be "solved by thread A?" Maybe there is a different way to solve your problem. Signals are older than threads, and they never were meant to meet the needs of a multi-threaded program.

Comment: I want to handle page fault in user space with low latency. For example, I use anonymous mmap to get a valid VMA, but I do not want kernel to manage this region. Then I access a virtual address in this region, this will trigger a page fault and falling in kernel mode. I want to modify kernel's page fault handler to do nothing but to send a thread signal to the faulting thread. Then, when back to faulting thread, it can observe the thread signal and solve the page fault before going on. In this case, current process-oriented signal can not work properly.

Comment: I'm not going to be any help with that. Last time I tried anything that ambitious, I had to do it in some flavor of BSD Unix because Linux wasn't invented yet. For that project, my step 1 was to invent a couple of new system calls. I guess I would do the same thing today, and not spend any time trying to re-purpose a legacy mechanism like signals.

Comment: Thank you, but I think re-purpose the legacy signal mechanism is not a bad idea. I can't image any new syscall that will be more efficient.